# Implement callback after %MyStruct{} has been created

Tags: elixir

In Elixir I want to enforce validation of a data structure upon its creation. To achieve it, I suppose to enforce calling a callback function that gets just created data structure and returns either this data structure if it is valid, or an error tuple.

What can be the way to implement it?

If I declare some behaviour like ValidatedStruct and implement the callback in the struct's module - then how could I enforce calling it upon the struct initialisation prior to returning new struct in the calling code?

Comment: You want this callback to be called automatically when a user uses the `%SomeModule{foo: bar}` syntax to create a struct?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, exactly.

Comment: Though, maybe, it would be enough to make such a callback available for client code in case it wants to check itself. And then calling the callback during further processing. I still don't know what is the best way to make such an integrity check in Elixir. Coming from Scala background.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot guarantee that a struct contains valid values in Elixir. A Struct is just a Map with a `__struct__` field containing an Atom (usually a Module name). You can take any map, add a `__struct__` field and it becomes that struct.

For example, here's me constructing a `MapSet` struct without any other field. `iex` can't even print the struct because the `Inspect` implementation of `MapSet` assumes there is a `map` key containing a map inside the struct:

```
iex(1)> %{__struct__: MapSet}
%Inspect.Error{message: "got FunctionClauseError with message \"no function clause matching in MapSet.to_list/1\" while inspecting \e[39m%{\e[0m\e[33m\e[36m__struct__: \e[0m\e[33m\e[36mMapSet\e[0m\e[33m\e[39m}\e[0m\e[33m"}
```

What Elixir libraries usually do is add a `new` function in the module which accepts arguments and returns `{:ok, struct}` on valid input and `{:error, "description"}` (or just `:error`) on failure. This does not prevent users from creating the struct using the `%ModuleName{}` syntax. You could add a simple safeguard against this by adding a `valid?` field which defaults to `false`, and then check for that value being true in all your functions. `Ecto.Changeset` uses a similar technique which makes `Repo.insert` not even try to insert the data in a database if there's an error in `Ecto.Changeset`. Again, this is trivial to bypass.

Here's an example:

```
defmodule MyStruct do
  defstruct [:x, :y, valid?: false]

  # We want `x` and `y` to always be integers.
  def new(x, y) when is_integer(x) and is_integer(y) do
    {:ok, %__MODULE__{x: x, y: y, valid?: true}}
  end
  def new(_, _), do: :error

  def print(%__MODULE__{x: x, y: y, valid?: true}) do
    IO.inspect {x, y}
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    IO.inspect MyStruct.new(1, 2)
    IO.inspect MyStruct.new(1, 2.3)
    {:ok, a} = MyStruct.new(1, 2)
    MyStruct.print(a)
    try do
      # This will throw an error because `valid?` will be false.
      MyStruct.print(%MyStruct{})
    rescue
      e -> IO.inspect e
    end
    # This however will work and there's no way to stop it.
    MyStruct.print(%MyStruct{x: "x", y: "y", valid?: true})
  end
end

Main.main
```

Output:

```
{:ok, %MyStruct{valid?: true, x: 1, y: 2}}
:error
{1, 2}
%FunctionClauseError{arity: 1, function: :print, module: MyStruct}
{"x", "y"}
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer! What I seek for - is not making it hard to bypass, but rather making the bypass attempt explicit for the code author. So that I, as an author of the client code, would easily notice if I bypass the check. Seems, I need to dig into Ecto Changeset's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the struct through a function which you can name `new` and call your validation method from there.

E.g: (NOT TESTED)

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct name: nil, errors: %{}

  def new(opts) do
    __struct__(__MODULE__, opts) |> validate
  end

  defp validate(user) do
    if !user.name, do: add_error(user, :name, "Name is required"), else: user
  end

  defp add_error(user, property, message) do
    %User{user | errors: Map.put(user.errors, property, message }
  end

  def valid?(user) do
    Enum.empty?(user.errors)
  end
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ always start a pipe with a term: `__MODULE__ |> __struct__(opts) |> validate`.

Comment: Thanks for example, @nicolas-garnil , I'll test it and write another comment with my observations.

Comment: In function `new ` you supposed to call `struct` (Kernel.struct/2), not `__struct__`. 
I don't want to store errors in the struct itself. Often it can be just wrapper around a single value. Like %OrderId{v: "some_order_id"}. Error reporting should be decoupled from the struct. I see it more monadic-like. It then could be used within the `with` block.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `with` block does not require an explicit term to keep errors, monadic-like behaviour could be easily achieved with pattern matching: `with %MyStruct{errors: nil} <- my_struct, do: SUCCESS, else %MyStruct{errors: errors} -> ERRORS(errors) end`.